# get to object of entity json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, object, encode

I do have an array:

```
$general_informations['company'] = $company_db
```

`$company_db` is an Entity with an object, like :

```
$city = $company_db->getCity();
```

Now I do `json_encode()`.

How can I get now the object `getCity()` in javascript?

Like:

```
var city = general_informations.company_db.getCity;
var city = general_informations.company_db.city;
```

Comment: `console.log` your object and see it's properties.

Comment: This is a poorly-formed question. You need to post the related code so we can try to help decipher what's going on. This is why you're getting down-votes.

Comment: `$city = $company_db->getCity();` in this expression, $company_db is an object and getCity() is the method. In $city you will get the return value of this method. And if you want this $city in js the do like this `var city = '<?php echo $city; ?>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_encode on a object creates json what includes all public properties from the object. private protected and all methods are not included

```
<?php
  class Sample {
    public $visibleProperty = true;
    protected $notVisibleProperty = false;
    private $invisibleProperty = false;
    public function getProperty(){
      return $notVisibleProperty;
    }
  }

  $test = new Sample();

  $json = json_encode($test); 
  echo $json; // {"visbleProperty": true}
?>
```

hope this helps to understand why you cant access your methods with js directly